# Have to pass the function name as parameter

Tags: java, ruby

I am coming from Ruby background. I have something like this in Ruby

For example, this is a method definition:

```
def fun
  puts 'Raja'
end
```

Now this is a method calling:

```
fun
```

Instead of calling `fun`, I can call the function as I have given below

```
send "fun"
```

This `send "fun"` will call the fun as well. The advantage of doing it this way is I can pass the function name also as a parameter. Is there any way I can achieve the same in Java? Or Is there any alternative found in Java?

Comment: The best solution is to use lambda's and functional interfaces

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, thank you very much.